# Android reverse animation does not respect duration

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-xml

I'm working on a super simple animation of a shake, using a few rotation animations put together. I'm having a problem where the repeat portion of the animation seems to ignore the duration and just jump back to the position rather than using the duration to rotate back up.

The way I currently have this set up:

1. First animation - Moves half the rotation distance to a new starting point.  Added this so that there isn't an ugly jump at the start of the animation.
2. Second animation - The majority.  Basically rocking back and forth from the max bounds. There is a set duration on a rotation that looks great when the animation is initially playing, but it jumps back when it repeats.
3. Third animation - The end, smoothly move the animation back to the starting position.

code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <rotate
        android:duration="240"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="2"/>
    <rotate
        android:startOffset="240"
        android:duration="480"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="5"
        android:toDegrees="-4"/>
    <rotate
        android:startOffset="720"
        android:duration="240"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="2"/>
</set>
```

An alternative i've been trying is to just have 1 full cycle of the animation in the xml, and then find a way to loop it, or run it x times in a row.  Haven't been able to get this to actually loop correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <rotate
        android:duration="240"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="2"/>
    <rotate
        android:startOffset="240"
        android:duration="480"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:toDegrees="-4"/>
    <rotate
        android:startOffset="720"
        android:duration="240"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="2"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it might be a bug on Android?  It seems to work correctly with ObjectAnimator as seen below.  This code works and respects the duration on the reverse and repeats.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="240"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="2"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="480"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="2"
        android:valueTo="-2"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="4"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="240"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="-2"
        android:valueTo="0"/>
</set>
```